# Add some bit stream to image png

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, type-conversion, png, bytesio

I've converted the png image to a base 2-bit sequence with the following program

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
from io import BytesIO
out = BytesIO()

with Image.open("download.png") as img:
img.save(out, format="png")
image_in_bytes = out.getvalue()
encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in image_in_bytes])
w = open("bitofimage", "w")
w.write(encoded_b2)
```

as a result, is a base 2. bit sequence

I CREATED A CRC PROCESS AND ADDED 8 BITS TO THE BIT SEW BEHIND IT.

And then convert back to PNG image with this code

```
a = open("bitadd_crc","r") //This Stream of bit has add with 8 bit crc
konv = a.read()
decoded_b2 = [int(konv[i:i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(konv), 8)]
with open('YANGDIKIRIM.png', 'wb') as f:
f.write(bytes(decoded_b2))

f.close()
w.close()
```

After being converted into an image again it worked, but when I unpacked it into a series of bits again, the 8-bit CRC added earlier was unreadable and converted into a part of the image. can anyone help me find the solution?
I hope there is help to complete my final school assignment

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the CRC to the image data, you may append the CRC to the end of the PNG file (as binary file).
Applications that read the new file (with few for bytes at the end) are going to ignore the redundant bytes.

- Copy the content of download.png to bitadd_crc.png
- Write the CRC (as two HEX digits or other format), to the end of bitadd_crc.png file.

The only difference of bitadd_crc.png and download.png is going to be the last two bytes.

---

Here is a code sample:

```python
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
from io import BytesIO
import crc8

out = BytesIO()

with Image.open("download.png") as img:
    img.save(out, format="png")
    image_in_bytes = out.getvalue()
    encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in image_in_bytes])
    #w = open("bitofimage", "w")
    #w.write(encoded_b2)

hash = crc8.crc8()
hash.update(image_in_bytes)  # Compute CRC using crc8 https://pypi.org/project/crc8/ (just for the example).
crc = hash.hexdigest().encode('utf8')

# Writing the CRC to bitadd_crc.png
################################################################################
# Copy the content of download.png to bitadd_crc.png and Write the CRC as two HEX digits, to the end of bitadd_crc.png file
# The only difference of bitadd_crc.png and download.png is going to be the last two bytes
with open('bitadd_crc.png', 'wb') as f:
    with open('download.png', 'rb') as orig_f:
        f.write(orig_f.read())  # Read the content of download.png and write it to bitadd_crc.png

    f.write(crc) # Write the CRC as two HEX digits, to the end of bitadd_crc.png file


# Reading the CRC from bitadd_crc.png
################################################################################
with open('bitadd_crc.png', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(-2, 2)  # # Go to the 2rd byte before the end
    crc_read = f.read(2)  # Read the last two bytes from the binary file.

print('crc = ' + crc.decode('utf8'))
print('crc_read = ' + crc_read.decode('utf8'))
```

---

Point for thought:
Consider to compute the CRC on the decoded PNG pixels (as bytes):

- Convert the image to NumPy array as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-into-a-numpy-array).
- Compute the CRC of the flattened NumPy array.
- Add the CRC as file metadata described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399070/how-do-i-save-custom-information-to-a-png-image-file-in-python).

In the suggested procedure, the CRC applies only the pixels of the image (not to the binary content of the PNG file).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, First i will try your recommendation code and learn it.

Comment: I want to ask again. If the binary content of the PNG file can't i add crc with following this code https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cyclic-redundancy-check-python/ ? . I make code convert image to binary stream add crc for send over udp and after that i will check again the crc in the receiver for checking is there someting error or not. Hopefully you can suggest me

Comment: There are many options. My suggestion (and example) is taking the file as a generic binay file, and ignore the fact that the file is an image. I can't give a complete diagnosis because you didn't post the part where you are adding the CRC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888306/add-bit-string-crc-to-image . There is the complete code where i add crc in the image. Hopefully you can help me. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you please edit your question? Create a single pice of code that we can execute and reproduce the problem. I think you don't really need to comute the CRC, you can just attach few data bytes like b'1234'. Then try to read the attached bytes. You will see that you cannot read the bytes, and that will be a nice and simple example to your problem.

Comment: Why the bytes that i attached before in content binary of image cannot read ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the reason from reading your code. Please edit your question, and add a simple example that reproduces the problem.